# Como desativar Ctrl + V do contextmenu?

Tags: c#, wpf

No textbox não pode de jeito nenhum colar, o código a seguir funciona certo:

```
private void Textbox_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Paste)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

O problema está mostrando no contextmenu ao clicar no mouse direito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como desativar Ctrl+V ?

Comment: vê se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9632/4713574

Comment: @RovannLinhalis veja a minha resposta !

Answer (score 3):

Código a seguir oculta "Ctrl+ V":

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro código a seguir, desabilita "Ctrl+V":

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" />
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" IsEnabled="False" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]